# Alternative of INTERVAL DAY() TO SECONDS() SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table definition as follows,

```
create table interval_test (
    roll_no number not null,
    start_time timestamp(6),
    end_time timestamp(6),
    time_interval INTERVAL DAY (9) TO SECOND (6) generated always as (end_time - start_time)
)
```

on inserting the data..

```
insert into interval_test( roll_no, start_time, end_time)
values (452, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  '02-03-22 1:20:52.096000000 PM');
```

This is the output that is generated

```
452(roll_no)    28-02-22 1:17:07.858000000 PM(start_time)   02-03-22 1:20:52.096000000 PM(end_time) +02 00:03:44.238000(time_interval)
```

Here the time_interval column is calculated and showing the interval +02 00:03:44.238000 in day to second format.

Is there a way I can achieve same functionality in SQL Server?

I am new to sql server..

Comment: SQL Server has computed columns... which you'd have found if you'd have read the docs.

Comment: @DaleK: I think the question is, what is the equivalent data type to `interval` in SQL Server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, wanted to know if there is any equivalent to INTERVAL datatype as in oracle

Comment: The difference can be more than 24 hours .. Is there a way I can store difference in days ?

Comment: You can use an `INT`, `BIGINT` or `DECIMAL` column to store any difference, just not with a "type", so then the column ideally has a conspicuous name (`DifferenceInDays`). That said, you appear to need the difference with greater precision than "days" (down to the millisecond) so you may want to increase your granularity.

Comment: To what purpose is the resulting column put? That is, how is it used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql Server doesn't have an `INTERVAL` datatype.
But it's possible to generate a string in that format.

And it's also possible to use a User-Defined Function in a computed column.  *(As long it's a deterministic UDF)*

The example below demonstrates that.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetIntervalStamp
> (
>    @FromDt2 DATETIME2, @ToDt2 DATETIME2
> )
> RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
> WITH SCHEMABINDING
> AS
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE @days INT, @ms BIGINT, @time TIME(3);
>   SET @days = DATEDIFF(day, @FromDt2, @ToDt2);
>   SET @ms = DATEDIFF_BIG(microsecond, CAST(@FromDt2 as TIME), CAST(@ToDt2 as TIME));
>   SET @time = DATEADD(ms, (@ms/10000)%1000, DATEADD(ss, @ms/10000000, 0));
>   RETURN CONCAT(IIF(SIGN(@days)<0,'-','+'), ABS(@days), ' ', @time);
> END;
> ```

> ```
> create table interval_test (
>     roll_no int not null,
>     start_time datetime2,
>     end_time datetime2,
>     time_interval as dbo.fnGetIntervalStamp(start_time, end_time) persisted
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into interval_test( roll_no, start_time, end_time)
> values (452, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  '2022-03-02 15:20:52.0960000');
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from interval_test
> ```

> | roll_no | start_time | end_time | time_interval |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 452 | 2022-02-28 14:31:35.9600000 | 2022-03-02 15:20:52.0960000 | +2 00:04:55.613 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=569058695a310ee66ec740447c9ef27c)*

Comment: There is no need for `PERSISTED` here. It's a widespread misconception that this is necessary to make it possible to index the computed column, but this is true only for floating-point values. It's also not necessarily the case that it brings performance benefits, since calculating the value on the fly for the queries that need it tends to be cheaper than storing it redundantly with every row (though this can vary per use case, of course).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the insight. The OP can just remove the `persistent` then. I'll keep the solution with it, more like a personal preference when it's computed from a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEDIFF()`, there is no equivalent of INTERVAL in SQL Server.

For instance:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2017/08/25', '2011/08/25') AS DateDiff;
```

would return you

```
-2192
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/7793

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no interval type in SQL Server, you can actually use the `datetime` type to also store intervals.
A 0 zero interval is presented as `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`
`datetime` supports not only subtraction operations but also addition operations.

```
declare @dttm_1 datetime = '2022-02-25 10:58:21'
declare @dttm_2 datetime = '2022-02-27 13:02:07'
declare @dttm_interval datetime

select cast(0 as datetime) as "cast(0 as datetime)"
-- 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

set @dttm_interval = @dttm_2 - @dttm_1

select @dttm_interval as "@dttm_interval = @dttm_2 - @dttm_1"
-- 1900-01-03 02:03:46.000

select @dttm_1 + @dttm_interval as "@dttm_1 + @dttm_interval"
-- 2022-02-27 13:02:07.000

select datediff(hour   ,0 ,@dttm_interval) as hours   -- 50
      ,datediff(minute ,0 ,@dttm_interval) as minutes -- 3003
      ,datediff(second ,0 ,@dttm_interval) as seconds -- 180226
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c7987f31d5e3d3c90bc1e11abc5979e)

Comment: I would not recommend this approach because it relies on fairly obscure behavior of `DATETIME`, a type that has precision issues; it is not supported with the newer `DATETIME2`, so using this ties you down unnecessarily, where a simple integer type for the interval would not. Having said that, with those caveats in mind this does work and I don't agree with the downvote.